# json response with arrays of different objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I want to sent a response to an ajax call that contains 2 arrays of different objects.
When i set

```
 dataType: "json",
```

the ajax call fails so i assume that is wrong the format the controller sends.

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
        $json2 = $serializer->serialize($readyproblems, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
        $json1 = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
        $json = '{"data1": ' . $json1 . '"data2":' . $json2 . '}';
        return new Response($json);
```

this will return

```
{"data1": [{"id":4,"Description":"solution 4"},{"id":1,"Description":"sol 1"}]"data2":[{"id":1,"Description":"problima1"},{"id":2,"Description":"problima2"}]}
```

at the the success of ajax i d like to get the data like

```
function callback(data) {
data.data1[0].property
data.data2[1].property 
}
```

also `JSON.parse(data);` causes error since the string is not right

Comment: There is a comma missing before "data2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma before "data2"

```
{
    "data1": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "Description": "solution 4"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Description": "sol 1"
        }
    ], "data2": [ // Comma added here
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Description": "problima1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Description": "problima2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's how to fix you're code

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
$json2 = $serializer->serialize($readyproblems, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
$json1 = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
$json = '{"data1": ' . $json1 . ',"data2":' . $json2 . '}';
return new Response($json);
```